# Computing nearest point in a cone of angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, matlab

*Figure 1*
[image]

In the above figure, there are 3 agents namely `i_1`, `i_2` and `i_3`. For each agent, I know the velocity (`v_x, v_y`) and the position (`x,y`).

I wish to compute the nearest agent within the cone of vision say `x` degrees  of an agent. (Cone of vision depicted above for `i_1`)

In above figure, considering the i_1: the computation should result in i_2.

My naive approach is to first calculate `i_1`'s direction taking `tan(vx/xy)`. Now compute a line in direction with  `i_1`'s coordinates. Then rotating the line `22.5` right and `22.5` left. Now iterate from left to right with step size=~`0.01` degrees and compute the intersection at each direction with distance from agent. Store the agent with least distance.

But this is highly inefficient. I would appreciate better approaches.

I asked the same question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656784/computing-nearest-point-in-a-cone-of-angle) but got no response. Therefore, thought about asking here.

Comment: Why not just calculate the distances and angles to all other agents and select the one closest that has a valid angle?

Answer (score -1):

I would draw a sphere two times the distance from i1 to i3 or i2 if you only want to work on i2. I don't know what type of software you may have to look at this in 3d instead of 2d. But you could place the cone within the sphere. To only track within the cone. It is easier to track in a sphere than a cone for locations. Then draw the cone in the sphere. To check on problems or locations. Have the software give warnings for cone locations.